# Adding parameters to an applied dataframe function

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, apply, python-3.7

Lets say I have a dataframe:

```
                 Pop_By_Area    CensusPop
 ID         
 100010401001000    77.0        77           
 100010401001001    294.0       294 
 100010401001002    20.0        20
 100010401001003    91.0        91  
 100010401001004    53.0        53
```

I want to create a function that compares 2 column values on a row and return a value for a new column thats the difference between the 2 columns:

```
 def pop_compare(row):
     pop_by_area_sum = row.Pop_By_Area
    census_pop_avg = float(row.CensusPop)
    diff = 0
    if (pop_by_area_sum != census_pop_avg):
        diff = abs(int(pop_by_area_sum - census_pop_avg))
    return diff

cb_pop_sum['Difference'] = cb_pop_sum.apply(pop_compare, axis=1)
```

No problem; works fine but I have to use the specific column name:

```
>                   Pop_By_Area CensusPop Difference   
 ID         
 100010401001000    77.0        77        0   
 100010401001001    294.0       294       0
 100010401001002    20.0        20        0
 100010401001003    91.0        91        0
 100010401001004    53.0        53        0
```

Now, suppose I want to use a similar function to compare any 2 columns in a larger data frame to return the difference. I'd need to add parameters for the comparison columns to the function in addition to row.

```
def pop_compare2(row, colA, colB):
    valA = row.colA
    valB = row.colB
    diff = 0
    if (valA != valB):
        diff = abs(int(valA - valB))
    return diff
```

This doesn't work, when I run the following:

```
c_A = "Pop_By_Area"
c_B = "CensusPop"
cb_pop_sum['Difference2'] = cb_pop_sum.apply(pop_compare2(colA=c_A, colB=c_B), axis=1)
cb_pop_sum.head()
```

It throws the error `TypeError: pop_compare2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but this should work:

```py
from io import StringIO
csv = StringIO("""
 ID                 Pop_By_Area    CensusPop      
 100010401001000    77.0        77           
 100010401001001    294.0       294 
 100010401001002    20.0        20
 100010401001003    91.0        91  
 100010401001004    53.0        53 
""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep='\s+')
df['Difference'] = df['Pop_By_Area'] - df['CensusPop']

def custom_func(subdf):
    x,y = subdf.values
    return x**3-y/123

df['Difference2'] = df[['Pop_By_Area', 'CensusPop']].apply(custom_func, axis=1)
```